# How to identify google-analytics and facebook-server requests?

Tags: javascript, php, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I have a web application where I want to keep track of the number of visitors to a certain page. What I do is to increment a variable that I store in a relational database, when a request comes to that page. I noticed that sometimes the variable is incremented by 3 instead of 1, and I found the reason why: when I visited the page, just after my visit, 2 extra visits are made to that page, one being from a Google server, the other from a Facebook server. I guess that these extra visits are because I use Google-analytics and Facebook-connect scripts in that page.

My question is how can I ignore these extra requests? How do I identify whether a request is coming from Google-analytics servers or Facebook servers? What's their IP ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution: look at the user_agent field of the http request. For google-analytics queries it's "Mediapartners-Google", for facebook-connect it is "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)". And [here is](http://tipstrickshowtos.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-identify-http-requests-that-are.html) how to implement this in Ruby on Rails.